# add item to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i read a lot in that forum, but i couldn't find a proper way to add all items to my dictionary... So maybe someone can help me!
first a explanation:

```
rows = cur.fetchall() 
columns=[desc[0] for desc in cur.description]  
GID_Distances = {}  
if len(rows) > 0:
    for row in rows:
      items = zip(columns, row)
      GID_Distances = {}
      for (name,  value) in items:
         GID_Distances[name]=value
```

rows is a list from a sql-statement. so in that list are several values with the same key... I just want to get something like a table 
something like this:
{['id': 1, 'point':2], ['id':2, 'point':3]} 
but for the loop above is the result just the last item, because it overwrites all before. Any ideas????

Comment: don't check that the length of a list is nonempty before you iterate over it. this is implicit in iterating over it.

Comment: You should accept Kenny's answer

Comment: if `cur` is a cursor on a db then there is probably a type of cursor that behaves like a dict.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an iterable of pairs i.e. `[(k1,v1),(k2,v2),...]`, you could apply `dict` on it to make it a dictionary. Therefore, your code could be written simply as

```
rows = cur.fetchall() 
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]  
# or: columns = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), cur.description))
#     don't call list() in Python 2.x.
GID_Distances = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in rows]
# note: use itertools.izip in Python 2.x
```

Comment: That worked perfect! uhu, so much shorter... great!
so, i will see if i can go on with that... have to change because i used the dictionary before!

Thanks for the fast help, great!

Answer (score 2):

you are redefining `GID_Distances` to a blank dictionary in the loop without first storing the value. store the rows in a list like so:

```
rows = cur.fetchall() 
columns=[desc[0] for desc in cur.description]  
results = []
for row in rows:
  GID_Distances = {} 
  items = zip(columns, row)
  for (name,  value) in items:
     GID_Distances[name]=value
  results.append(GID_Distances)
```

Comment: but then this error occurs:
NameError: global name 'GID_Distances' is not defined

Comment: there must be a typo then. there is no good reason for that to happen. For example, you are accessing `columns` just fine and it's defined at the same block level as `GID_Distances`. Check that your spelling is the same in both places.

Comment: don't think that there is a typo, because it's the same code... i just added a #...

Comment: double check to be sure. I find a copy and paste of the variable names often works. Are there any functions involved? This sort of thing can happen because of messed up indentation.

Comment: but the error occurs in the line of the loop... thats the first time i use GID_Distances, because i deleted the row before...

Comment: and you are defining it to be an empty dict before you enter the loops, correct?

Comment: yes, thats right! before the loop, so i thought at the end it has to be filled with the three rows!

Comment: I messed up in the code but that doesn't have anything to do with the NameError bug you've been having. Try the new version and see.

Comment: the new python version? can't do that because i am writing a plugin for qgis and thats just working with 2.5, or sth like that...

Comment: no. I modified the code in my post. Try that and see if it works. look at the post. you will end up with a list of dictionaries name results. each dictionary is a row. you can rename to taste but this code will do what you want.

Comment: sorry, haven't seen that! 
mh, it's a good idea to store the hole thing in a list... the code is not working properly, but i hope it will... :)... need some time, let you know 
AND: Thanks a lot!

Comment: just go with kenny's solution